# Query with CursorLoader in ListFragment isn't returning any data

Tags: android, android-cursorloader

I continue to struggle with getting a query to work with a CursorLoader in a ListFragment. I suspect part of my problem is that I'm unsure about certain details. I have an xml file, myfragment.xml, which defines the two fragments in my app. The first fragment, my ListFragment, is identified by:

```
android:id="@+id/frag_mylist"
```

When I call SimpleCursorAdapter in my ListFragment class, I believe I should do this:

```
String[] dataColumns = { "fieldname", "_id" };
    int[] viewIDs = { R.id.frag_mylist };
    mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.myfragment, null, dataColumns, viewIDs, 0);
    setListAdapter(mAdapter);
    getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, info, (LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>) this);
```

where info is a Bundle that I've passed from a previous activity. Is that right? Also, I've seen some examples with 0 as the last parameter for SimpleCursorAdapter, others with CursorAdapter.FLAG_REGISTER_CONTENT_OBSERVER. What's the difference?  Finally, [this page](http://developer.android.com/training/load-data-background/setup-loader.html) *may* indicate that I have to retrieve a LoaderManager in my code like so:

```
private LoaderManager mLoaderManager;
public void onCreate(savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
mLoaderManager = this.getSupportLoaderManager();
```

}

but this is the only place I've seen this. Is this necessary? I'm hoping that getting answers to these questions will help me dig down to why my query is returning no results. I'm fairly confident that my database is being created and populated at this point.  Thanks much!

As requested below, here are the three methods of my LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks interface:

```
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
    String selection = "level='" + args.getString("Level") + "'";
    return (Loader<Cursor>) new CursorLoader(getActivity(), MY_URI,
            PROJECTION, selection, null, null); 
}
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor cursor) {
    switch (loader.getId()) {
      case LOADER_ID:
        mAdapter.swapCursor((android.database.Cursor) cursor);
        break;
    }


}
public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
    mAdapter.swapCursor(null);

}
```

Let me add that I've verified through the debugger that args.GetString("Level") in the onCreateLoader method is "Beginning", which is what it should be.

Comment: Try to isolate the code around your problem. So your loader doesn't return data, right? Can you post how you've implemented the `Loader`(those three methods of the `LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks` interface) in the `frag_mylist` fragment? Are you sure you implemented the loaders like you should?

Comment: Thanks again Luksprog. See above in my original question for the three methods

Comment: Have you tested to see if you have data(if it's not empty) in the `Cursor` returned in the `onLoadFinished` method? If you only have one `Loader` there is no need to test for `Loader_ID` especially as you pass 0 for the `id` with `initLoader`. Also, those cast aren't necessary, you're cluttering the code with them.

Comment: You're right, the cursor is null. I'm going to start a new forum thread because it seems my insert statement is not inserting anything. Thanks for helping me to focus.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line within your onLoadFinished after you swap the cursor

```
mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
```

Comment: The method `swapCursor` actually does this in its implementation.